# What does the "it" in "He's the one that's gonna get it" refer to?

Tags: the-matrix, language-explanation

In *The Matrix Reloaded* (2003), Cas says to Link about Zee:

> Cas: You be careful with her.
>
> Zee: Don't worry about me. He's the one that's gonna get **it**.

What does the "it" in "get it" refer to?

Comment: It means he will suffer in some form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an [idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+it). In this case, the fifth definition is the one that applies.

> get it
>
> 1. To pick up, retrieve, or receive something.
>    *I paid for her present online, but I need to go get it from the store.*
>    *A: "The baby knocked her bottle onto the ground." B: "Don't worry, I'll get it."*
> 2. To understand or comprehend something.
>    *I've read this chapter three times, but I'm just not getting it.*
>    *You might want to slow down your lectures, I don't think the rest of the class gets it.*
>    *A: "Remember, you need to press this button three times before turning on the engine." B: "OK, got it."*
> 3. To answer the telephone or door.
>    *I hear the doorbell ringing—would you mind getting it?*
> 4. To pay for something, especially for or on behalf of someone else.
>    *Don't worry about dinner tonight, I've got it.*
>    *I'll get it, you put your money away.*
> 5. **To receive a severe reprimand, scolding, retaliation, or punishment.
>
>    *Oh man, I'm going to get it from my parents when they find out I wrecked the car!*
>
>    *You little punk, you're going to get it if you ever show your face around here again!***

To elaborate, Zee is saying that Link is about to be reprimanded/scolded for spending so much time away on the Nebuchadnezzar, instead of being at home with her. Note that that's the first thing she brings up with Link after Cas leaves the room with the kids.

> LINK: I’m gonna get what?
>
> ZEE: Every ship out there has been home two, even three times more than the Nebuchadnezzar.
>
> LINK: Come on, Zee! I thought we were past this!
>
> ZEE: We’ll get past this when you start operating another ship.
>
> <sub>*The Matrix Reloaded* (2003)</sub>